# Как посчитать количество секунд в заданном году?

Tags: java

```
secodsInYear = LocalDate.now().lengthOfYear() * 24 * 3600;
```

Таким образом посчитаем в текущем, а нужно в заданном

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LocalDate.of(year, month, day).lengthOfYear()
```

Тест:

```
System.out.println(LocalDate.of(2019, 1, 1).lengthOfYear() + " " + LocalDate.now().lengthOfYear());
```

Вывод:

```
365 366
```

Если надо узнать, сколько дней в году, отличающимся от нынешнего на `n`, то подойдут такие функции:

```
.minusYears(long yearsToSubtract)
.plusYears(long yearsToAdd)
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно